# How to load a view by default instead of Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I'm working on a .NET 6 web api and I've configured the Program.cs to use Swagger UI when in development mode. How can I change this so that I still have access to Swagger UI but by default load the default view?

For example, when I run my project, it loads `https://localhost:7004/swagger/index.html` instead I want to load `https://localhost:7004` but still have access to `https://localhost:7004/swagger/index.html`

Current Program.cs:

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=ControllerName}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your project's priperties (screenshot below -)

[image: Project properties]

Under the 'Debug'section, click on 'Open debug launch profiles UI'. This should open the UI shown below -

[image: Debug section of project properties dialog box]

Remove the text 'swagger', leave it blank, restart your application. This should navigate to -

[image: Remove 'Swagger' from project properties dialog box.]

Note that you can still enter full path to swagger link to navigate to it -

[image: Navigation to swagger page]

Answer (score 1):

open launchsettings.json and remove launch url

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:41869",
      "sslPort": 44362
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "WebApplication2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger", // remove this
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7189;http://localhost:5189",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger", // remove this
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```